# Variable assignment in function

Tags: python, function, variables, game-physics

I'm writing a basic fighting game and am trying to make it so that with each attack it subtracts the amount of the attack from the enemy's health and prints the enemy's current health. However, the health resets to its original amount after I run the script once and loop it. How can I resign the enemies health with the current health?

Here is the script:

```
import random

while True:
    HEALTH = 20
    ENEMY_HEALTH = 20

    def punch():
        mylist = (xrange(0,3))
        x = random.choice(mylist)
        if x == 3:
            print"your hit was very effective enemy lost 3 hp"
            print("Enemy Health is" ENEMY_HEALTH - x)
        if x == 2:
            print "Your punch was effective enemy lost 2 hp"
            print("Enemy Health is" ENEMY_HEALTH - x)
        if x == 1:
            print "enemy lost 1 point"
            print("Enemy Health is" ENEMY_HEALTH - x)

    def kick():
        mylist = (xrange(0,5))
        x = random.choice(mylist)
        if x > 3:
            "%d" % x
            print"your kick was very effective enemy lost %d hp"
            print("Enemy Health is", ENEMY_HEALTH - x)
        if x > 1 < 3:
            "%d" % x
            print "Your kick was effective enemy lost %d hp"
            print("Enemy Health is" ENEMY_HEAlTH - x)
        if x == 1:
            print "enemy lost 1 point"
            print("Enemy Health is" ENEMY_HEALTH - x)

    def attackChoice(c):
        if c == "punch":
            punch()
        if c == "kick":
            kick()

    c = raw_input("Choice Attack\nKick Or Punch: ")
    attackChoice(c)
```

I want it to print:

```
choose attack
kick or punch:kick
enemy lost 3 hp
enemy's heath is 17
choose attack
kick or punch:punch
enemy lost 1 hp
enemy's health is 16
```

Comment: You never change `ENEMY_HEALTH`

Comment: Also, you're defining your functions repeatedly in the loop... why?

Comment: i dont know im sure there is an easier way but im relatively new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As Blender pointed out you are not changing the value of ENEMY_HEALTH you are just subtracting x from it and printing it without assigning that value back.
- move your initial assignment out of the while loops.
- you have extra string thing in your kick code
- use randint instead of building a list and picking one

maybe like:

```
import random
health = 20
enemy_health = 20

def punch():
    global enemy_health
    x = random.randint(1,3)
    enemy_health -= x
    if x == 3:
        print"your hit was very effective enemy lost 3 hp"
    if x == 2:
        print "Your punch was effective enemy lost 2 hp"
    if x == 1:
        print "enemy lost 1 point"
    print "Enemy Health is", enemy_health

def kick():
    global enemy_health
    x = random.randint(1,5)
    enemy_health -= x
    if x > 3:
        print "your kick was very effective enemy lost %d hp" % x
    if x > 1 < 3:
        print "Your kick was effective enemy lost %d hp" % x
    if x == 1:
        print "enemy lost 1 point"
    print "Enemy Health is", enemy_health

def attackChoice(c):
    if c == "punch":
        punch()
    if c == "kick":
        kick()

while True:
    c = raw_input("Choice Attack\nKick Or Punch: ")
    attackChoice(c)
```

Comment: it tells me that the                                               UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enemy_health' referenced before assignment

Comment: @ChristianCareaga did you lowercase all references to enemy_health?

Comment: @ChristianCareaga oh right, sorry, to change a global variable in local scope you should let it know you are using the global variable, fixed example

Comment: as a side note, its probably better not to use a global variable, but to have the player and enemy as objects with member variables

Answer (score 2):

You reset HEALTH and ENEMY_health in each loop step. You have to initialize them outside of the loop, and do you manipulations inside of the loop, like this:

```
HEALTH = 20
ENEMY_HEALTH = 20    
while True:
    #your code
    ENEMY_HEALTH = ENEMY_HEALTH - x
```

Also, you need to explicitly set the new value, like shown in the example snippet.

Also, please read the python style guide:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

All uppercase names like HEALTH are used for constants, but you don' want it to mean constant, so please you use lowercase...